# ValueError: unsupported format character '{' (0x7b) at index

Tags: python, hiera

I have this block of python code ...

```
 79         print "debug top is [" + top + "]"
 80         print "debug package is [" + package + "]"
 81         print "debug version is [" + version + "]"
 82         print "debug password is [" + password + "]"
 83         print "debug app_image_url is [" + app_image_url + "]"
 84         print "debug apptitle is [" + apptitle + "]"
 85 #       get_filenames_from_zip_file (app_zip_url)
 86 #       sys.exit(0)
 87         print """---
 88 top: '%s'
 89 package: '%s'
 90 version: %s
 91 password: '%s'
 92 make_audiobook::package_name: "%%{hiera('package')}"
 93 make_audiobook::version: "%%{hiera('version')}"
 94 make_audiobook::mp3filesdir: "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}/res/raw"
 95 make_audiobook::app_image::app_image_url: '%s'
 96 make_audiobook::app_image::resource_path:  "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}"
 97 make_audiobook::app_image::appdir:  "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}"
 98 make_audiobook::app_image::appname:  "%{::appname}"
 99 make_audiobook::app_javacode::appname:          "%%{::appname}"
100 make_audiobook::app_javacode::password:         "%%{hiera('password')}"
101 make_audiobook::app_javacode::apptitle:         "%s"
102 make_audiobook::app_javacode::package:          "%%{hiera('package')}"
103 make_audiobook::app_javacode::path_to_code:     "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}/src/com/%%{hiera('package')}/%%{::appname}"
104 make_audiobook::app_javacode::path_to_androidmanifest:     "%%{hiera('top')}/%%{::appname}/%%{::appname}"
105 make_audiobook::app_javacode::version:          "%%{hiera('version')}"
106 make_audiobook::app_javacode::tracks: """ % (top, package, version, password, app_image_url, apptitle)
```

When I run my script I get this error in the output:

```
debug top is [/home/get_links/TEMPLATE_FILES]
debug package is [redcricket]
debug version is [1]
debug password is [XXXXXX]
debug app_image_url is [https://ia801509.us.archive.org/7/items/song_of_the_wave_1703_librivox/songwave_1703.jpg]
debug apptitle is [Song of the Wave, and Other Poems]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./make_hiera_data_from_librivox_api.py", line 137, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./make_hiera_data_from_librivox_api.py", line 106, in main
    make_audiobook::app_javacode::tracks: """ % (top, package, version, password, app_image_url, apptitle)
ValueError: unsupported format character '{' (0x7b) at index 415
```

I cannot see anything wrong in that block of code. Maybe a second pair eyes would be helpful?

Comment: The lines `97 make_audiobook::app_image::appdir:  "%{hiera('top')}/%{::appname}"` and `98 make_audiobook::app_image::appname:  "%{::appname}"` need their `%` doubled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the instances of `%{` need to be replaced with `%%{`

For instance this

```
 %{::appname}
```

should be

```
 %%{::appname}
```

Comment: Why is this? I don't see that in the python3 documentation.

Comment: @cjm2671, %% is needed because of the string formatting that's used (the % operator). [Printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#printf-style-string-formatting) is the relevant section of Python's documentation. It states that conversion specifiers begin with '%' and an additional '%' (as convertion type) results in single '%'.